# Как вставить значения отправленные пользователем боту в Базу Данных sqlite3

Tags: sql, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, sqlite3

При отправке пользователем своего ФИО, оно должно заносится в БД. Но почему-то этого не происходит.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('telega.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (
  fio text,
  city text,
  tel int,
  photo_id int,
  kom text
  )""")

conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):        
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши своё ФИО, герой")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
  
          
def get_name(message):
  global fio
  fio = message.text
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши свой номер телефона')
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_tel)
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO info (fio) VALUE (fio)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не делаете commit изменений. После `cursor.execute` для сохранения изменений должен быть `conn.commit()`

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO info (fio) VALUE (?)', 
    (fio,)   
)
conn.commit()
```